# Identificando membros de uma mesma família

Tags: python, machine-learning

gostaria de saber o que posso utilizar em machine learning ou outro tipo de ferramenta para o seguinte problema:
Tenho uma lista de nomes completos e gostaria de identificar dentre os mesmos quais são parentes pela similaridade do sobrenome.
O que posso utilizar?

Answer (score 1):

Opa, acho difícil você conseguir isso usando machine learning uma vez que você teria que atribuir um label nos dados para membros de uma mesma família. Se o problema é só verificar quem em uma lista possui o mesmo sobrenome e classificar essa pessoa como sendo da mesma família, você consegue resolver isso simplesmente fazendo um loop na lista, encontrar os sobrenomes iguais, recuperar o nome completo e jogar em outras listas ou arrays.

Comment: Entendi, os caras do serenata de amor resolveram isso utilizando machine learning